# Can't disable rpcbind

Tags: 14.04, services

I got `rpcbind` and `rpc.statd` running on the boot

```
~ > sudo netstat -tpln
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      824/rpcbind     
tcp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1683/dnsmasq    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:17500           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3232/dropbox    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:17600         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3232/dropbox    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:17603         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3232/dropbox    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:49707           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      901/rpc.statd   
tcp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                    LISTEN      824/rpcbind     
tcp6       0      0 :::17500                :::*                    LISTEN      3232/dropbox    
tcp6       0      0 :::42664                :::*                    LISTEN      901/rpc.statd
```

I want to disable them from running.

```
    ~ > sudo update-rc.d rpcbind disable
    update-rc.d: warning:  start runlevel arguments (none) do not match rpcbind Default-Start values (S)
    update-rc.d: warning:  stop runlevel arguments (none) do not match rpcbind Default-Stop values (0 1 6)
     System start/stop links for /etc/init.d/rpcbind do not exist.
```

But it does exist!

```
~ > ls /etc/init.d/
acpid*             cron@               i8kbuttons*         ondemand*       resolvconf*               thin*
anacron*           cups*               i8kmon*             openbsd-inetd*  rpcbind*                  udev*
apparmor*          cups-browsed*       irqbalance*         osspd*          rsync*                    umountfs*
apport*            dbus*               isc-dhcp-server*    postgresql*     rsyslog*                  umountnfs.sh*
atd*               dns-clean*          kerneloops*         pppd-dns*       saned*                    umountroot*
atop*              ebtables*           killprocs*          procps*         screen-cleanup@           unattended-upgrades*
avahi-daemon*      friendly-recovery@  kmod*               pulseaudio*     screen-cleanup.dpkg-new*  urandom*
binfmt-support*    gdm*                lightdm*            rc*             sendsigs*                 vboxautostart-service*
bluetooth*         grub-common*        lm-sensors*         rc.local*       single*                   vboxballoonctrl-service*
bootchart*         halt*               motion*             rcS*            skeleton                  vboxdrv*
brltty*            hddtemp*            networking*         README          spamassassin*             vboxweb-service*
console-cyrillic*  hibernate*          nfs-kernel-server*  reboot*         speech-dispatcher*        virtualbox*
console-setup*     hostapd*            ntop*               redis-server*   sudo*                     x11-common*
```

How can I manage that?

Comment: I can see `rpcbind` in the output of `ls /etc/init.d/`. What version of Ubuntu is this?

Comment: As you can seen in tags it's 14.04

Comment: Lets check the status: `sudo service --status-all | grep rpcbind`

Comment: I can't do that right now, sorry. I'll do that tomorrow. Thank you!

Comment: Your command shows that rpcbind is disabled. Also netstat shows no open ports of rpcbind. Strangely it no longer operates.

Comment: I believe this is what you wanted?

Answer (score 2):

yes, 
`update-rc.d rpcbind disable` or `update-rc.d rpcbind remove`
both doesn't help in that case.
Probably because there are no such scripts in any of rc?.d directories.
But what really helps is:

```
sudo mv /etc/init/rpcbind.conf ~
sudo mv /etc/init/rpcbind-boot.conf ~
```

So you get rid of its configs used for boot (move to any safe place).
Then

```
reboot

service --status-all
```

Now it will show you

```
[ - ]  rpcbind
```

Even so it doesn't look nice - it works anyway, you should ask ubuntu guys why is it so strange.